# volatile const int meaning in C?

Tags: c

I am reading a [book](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Programming_In_Ansi_C.html?id=3fZa9af1KtYC&redir_esc=y) on C.
It mentions a concept which does not make sense to me.
What I know is that the compiler sometimes optimises code by removing variables which it feels would not affect an expression. So if we specify volatile to a variable, it does not remove this variable from any expression.

So the book introduces something like this:

```
volatile const int a = 1;
```

The explaination is only a couple of lines, none of which makes sense to me.
Can somebody please explain why would be there a need of such a variable?

**PS:** I understand the concept of **volatile**, what I dont understand is the concept of **volatile const**.

Comment: There's a whole [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable) on it.

Comment: This has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592762/difference-between-const-const-volatile

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822386/the-volatile-keyword-in-c-language

Comment: I understand the concept of volatile, I am asking about volatile const.

Comment: @unwind, sorry it SO automatically picked up the title for a question which I did not post

Comment: @notbad your linked question does not discuss `volatile const` types, but only `volatile` types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `volatile const` variable is one whose value may change due to external influences, and which cannot be written to.

Comment: thanks for understanding my question in the first place. But if the value of a variable is changing then how can it be const?

Comment: `const` means you cannot write to it. That doesn't mean the value can never change; the variable may map to a hardware register which reads values from a sensor, or something. This is where the `volatile` comes in.

Comment: Moreover, it may be changed with const-cast, or by another function/thread where it isn't declared `const` (quite common approach).

Comment: @keltar: The C standard does not define the behavior if an attempt is made to modify an object **defined** as const. If code has a pointer to a const type but the pointer is pointing to an object that was not originally defined as const, then it is permitted to convert the pointer to a pointer to non-const and to modify the object via the new pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i was talking more about extern. But yes, that thing too.

Answer (score 1):

Volatile const means value cannot be changed  programmatically but value can be changed indirectly, for eg if the variable is mapped to device register, then value can be modified by the device.