# extern volatile in multi source files

Tags: c, multithreading

I have some global variables that I need to share on multi source files. I have read [How do I share variables between different .c files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045501/how-do-i-share-variables-between-different-c-files) and do as following:

`fileA.h`:

```
extern int a;
```

`fileA.c`:

```
int a;
// using a variable here
```

Everything compile well and work fine. But because I program on multithread environment, so I put `volatile` keyword before each variable. so now is :

`fileA.h`:

```
extern volatile int a;
```

`fileA.c`:

```
int a;
// using a variable here
```

But when I use this way, I meet error when compiling:

> error: conflicting type qualifiers for ‘a’ in file included from
>   fileA.c:4:0:

Please explain for me why, and how to fix this? Should we use `volatile` in this case?

Comment: You need to put the volatile modifier on all declarations and definitions of the same extern variable.  For a discuss on volatile see this [stackoverflow: the volatile keyword in C language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822386/the-volatile-keyword-in-c-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any declarations for a variable should agree with its actual definition.  So if the declarations in the include files for `extern volatile int a;` should have an associated `volatile int a;` in the file where the variable is actually defined.

Also see this article [How to use C's volatile keyword](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword) including some information about multi-threaded applications.

Be aware that with multi-thread applications you may need to use some kind of locking or other mutual exclusion mechanism with a shared variable.  See [Why is volatile not considered useful in multi-threaded C or C++ programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming)

The main thing that the volatile keyword does is to inform the compiler that a variable may change from some action outside of the current scope so it affects how the compiler goes about generating machine code.

See this brief article [Compiler optimization and the volatile keyword](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_CJAEGDEA.htm).

And see this Dr. Dobbs article [volatile: The Multithreaded Programmer's Best Friend](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766)

Comment: @ : I meet this warning when compile with `volatile` keyword before pthread_mutex_t variable :  `passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_mutex_init’ discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type` Can you explain for me why, please ? Thanks :)

Comment: The use of volatile in any multi-threaded C program is pretty much guaranteed to be a serious bug. That's not what volatile was intended for and is not what it does. Best case it will just hide a bug. For example the code in "How to use C's volatile keyword" does not guarantee that `task1` will ever terminate.

Comment: @hqt, there are only a few circumstances where using `volatile` makes sense and passing a volatile as a function argument is not one of those.  The main use of `volatile` is to inform the compiler that some global memory location is being modified by something else so use the memory location directly rather than caching the value.  Mostly I have seen it used in embedded programs to read from some memory location that is used by something else especially with a polling type of loop or something similar.  It sounds to me like the compiler is warning you of an improper use of `volatile`.