# Compiler optimizations in gcc

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction

I have a code in C and I am running some tests. I need to access an array, but in "read-only" mode. I am doing something like this:

```
for (int i= 0; i < 1000; i++){
    int a = shared_array[rand() % 64];
    int b = shared_array[rand() % 64];
}
```

My question is: How can I fetch a value from memory and be sure that the compiler is not optimizing it by removing these instructions, given that in my test I am doing nothing with those values.
Even if I add an operation `int v = a + b`, again **v** is not used anywhere else, so it could be  ignored.

I am using gcc with -O3, and I need to do it that way to be able to compare it against results from another source.

Comment: You could of course add them to an accumulator declared outside the loop, so that each iteration does have an impact on the result.

Comment: not related to the question, but replacing `% 64` with `& 63` may improve performance a bit (if it's not hidden by memory latency). Also - this doesn't guarantee uniform distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical way you force the compiler to actually read an otherwise unused variable is to make it `volatile`. This should guarantee the compiler actually read/write the variable from RAM when it is used.

Comment: It _is_ guaranteed to work by the C standard. Whether or not GCC follows the C standard is another matter.

Comment: @Jens indeed, it is a C++ concept. Didn't notice this was a C question. I removed the confusion `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `a` and `b` in a function that is not defined in your current compilation unit (source file).

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `volatile` tells the compiler to not optimize that code. This applies for both variables and functions. You can even do this on inline assembly, which is a more advanced topic. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5822567/2166310).

It is usually applied after the type specifier, e.g. `int volatile i = 0;`.

Comment: `volatile T` == `T volatile`, unless `T` is a pointer of sorts.